# Как правильно посчитать длину массива?

Tags: массивы, ассемблер, masm32

Скажите пожалуйста как правильно посчитать длину массива?
Я вот сделал набросок для подсчёта длины массива, но он почему-то не хочет компилироваться...

> error A2070: invalid instruction operands

```
include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc
.data
 arr byte 14 dup (?) 
.code

start:
 lea esi, arr
 mov eax, 00
 mov [esi], eax
 mov eax, 11
 mov [esi+1], eax
 mov eax, 22
 mov [esi+2], eax
 mov eax, 55
 mov [esi+14], eax
 sub arr, esi // как я понимаю, это я вычитаю позицию конца и начало массива, желая посчитать длину
 exit
end start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `sub` вычитает из первого операнда второй операнд и кладет в первый операнд. У вас первый операнд - числовая константа (адрес начала массива), записать туда ничего нельзя.
2. Если бы у вас в `esi` был указатель на конец массива, то достаточно было бы поменять операнды местами, и в `esi` попал бы размер массива. Но так как в коде у вас `esi` никак не меняется (операции вида `mov [esi+N], eax` никак не влияют на значение `esi`, и не должны влиять), то это вам не поможет.

Как бы сработало (но было бы довольно некрасиво):

```
lea esi, arr
mov eax, 00
mov [esi], eax
mov eax, 11
lea esi, [arr+1]
mov [esi], eax
mov eax, 22
lea esi, [arr+2]
mov [esi], eax
mov eax, 55
lea esi, [arr+14]
mov [esi], eax
add esi, 4 ; добавляем размер последнего добавленного элемента
sub esi, offset arr ; из конца массива вычитаем начало, получаем размер
```

Также обратите внимание, вы записываете значения из 32-битных регистров в перекрывающиеся адреса. При проходе по массиву по возрастанию индексов у вас просто следующее число будет затирать последние 3 байта предыдущего. Т.к. у вас числа небольшие (умещаются в 1 байт), то вы этого не заметите. Но если проходить по массиву от конца к началу, то каждый следующий элемент, который вы запишете, будет затирать 3 байта после себя (которые были записаны ранее). В данной программе вам просто нужно заменить `eax` на `al`, т.к. у вас по факту массив байт.

**Как правильно посчитать длину массива:** вы либо знаете ее заранее (в данном случае вы сами указали, что размер массива 14 байт), либо, если выделено памяти с запасом, и вы, например, читаете из файла, то нужна отдельная переменная (в памяти или регистре - как удобнее), куда вы будете записывать, сколько элементов по факту было считано. Перед каждым чтением проверяем, что мы не выйдем за границы массива, после чтения увеличиваем количество прочитанных элементов на 1.

Comment: Кстати, [esi+14] за границами массива

Comment: @Mike, и это тоже. Хотел написать про это, но в процессе забыл.